# sort phase in spark plan

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple spark job doing below operations:

- read 1 day of csv .gz compressed data, (>10K files)
- basic transforms using withColumn to derive additional columns
- create a delta table if not already exists, partitioned by year,month,day
- write to delta table, using partition overwrite mode

```
#read
# read
h_data = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
    .option("sep", ",") \
    .option("escape", '"') \
    .option("multiline", "true") \
    .option("compression", "gzip") \
    .schema(<path>) \
    .csv(source_path)

# basic transform

# create table if not exists

delta_table_exists_or_not = DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark,target_path)
if not delta_table_exists_or_not:
    DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark) \
        .tableName(f"{catalog_name}.{schema_name}.{table_name}") \
        .location(target_path) \
        .addColumns(<write_schema>) \
        .partitionedBy(partition_columns) \
        .execute()
# write
h_data.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic") \
    .saveAsTable(f"{catalog_name}.{schema_name}.{table_name}")
```

**Question**:  Plans looks good. Only catch is plan has `sort` below, however we are not performing any sort. My understanding is sort is expensive operation. So why spark is doing sort below or how to check in the spark web UI, more details on code causing sort?
Plan:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example including code and input data, so that reviewers can replicate your situation?